# Thermofluid mechanics, calculating load on a steel water tank

Tags: forces, pressure, water

An open cylindrical water tank 2.4m diameter rests on three legs evenly positioned around the periphery of its circular base. The base and sides of the tank are made from steel with relative density 7.8 and thickness 20mm. If the tank is 2.1m high determine the load on each leg when the tank is empty, and full 
The volume of the steel in the sides of the tank can be approximated by V=dth

i tried calculating it and i got an answer however i didnt even use the volume equation, tho why would they give it in the question if im not going to use it?
that's why i'm asking for your help, i used $F=((\rho*g*h)+101\mathrm{kPa})$*area

Comment: what do you mean by density and area? Maybe the density of steel and the area of the circle with 2.4m diameter? 
If so, then... since the tank is not filled with stell, this would be wrong

Comment: yes, density of steel and area of steel, it doesnt work out, could you tell me what formula i would need to use please

Comment: if you took the area of steel (i.e. the thin ring of diameter 2.4m and width 20mm), then it's right. Well, still not quite, since the 101kPa dont belong there (they act from below too), and you forgot the bottom plate :)
Why don't you just calculate the mass

Comment: if i calculate the mass, than multiply it by gravity, to get the weight, it says open tank so i can't add the atm pressure to force, i have to calculate in regard to pressure

Comment: the atmospheric pressure does nothing, it's there everywhere and cancels itself out. Or to be more precise, it's *very slightly* decreasing with height - if you consider this deviation you get just the buoyant force from air on the tank. So this is equivalent to replacing $\rho_\mathrm{steel}$ by $\rho_\mathrm{steel}-\rho_\mathrm{air}$

Comment: in short: forget about the air pressure, the load on each leg is a third of the weight of the tank

Comment: and when the tank is full, you have to add the mass of water; this is of course equivalent to using your formula, since $h*$area is just the volume

Comment: i kind of understand it, i will solve it in 5 minutes and post it here, if u can pls hep check it for me thank you

Comment: is it right pls

Comment: V(steel) = 
 pi*(2.4 m)(0.02m)(2.1m) + pi(1.2m)^2(0.02m) 
 = pi*(0.02 m)(5.04 m^2 + 1.44m^2) 
 = pi*(0.02m)(6.48 m^2) = 0.4072 m^3. 
 Mass(steel) = (7800 kg/m^3)*(0.4072 m^3) 
 = 3176 kg. 
 Load on each leg of empty tank is 
 (1/3)(9.8 m/s^2)(3176 kg) = 10.37 kN. 

 When the tank is full, the volume of water is 
 pi*(1.18 m)^2*(2.08 m) = 9.10 m^3, 
 having a mass of 9100 kg and exerting a force of 
 89.167 kN, one-third of which would be 
 29.72 kN. So the load on each leg when the tank is full would be 40.1 kN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the solution you posted in your last comment is good.

With the sole criticism, that it is a little too precise. If the density of steel has only two digits, then the result should not have 4 as in 10.37kN
But this is very advanced criticism :)

Also minor points, to be even more precise:
for the circumference volume of the mantle you could equally well insert $2.36$m instead of $2.4$m - it's something in between, actually.
Also, the radius of the bottom should be only $2.36$m, since the you counted the part outside in the mantle already.
What I want to say: don't try to make it too precise, since some of the values (density in this case) don't allow this anyway. Your water volume is exact, but not substracting the thickness would be sufficient also. But it's good.

Comment: oh alright, thank you a lot ! at least someone helped me with feedback, my professor doesnt :)